# Javascript multiple array push() differences

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have problem with pushing data. I want to prepare data (time,temperature,humidity) for plotting (Dygraphs). But when I´m filling variable data with this one code (see below) I don´t get graph.

```
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++){
  var t = new Date (time[i]);
  data.push(t);
  for(var n = 0; n < 2; n++){
    data.push([data_graph[n][i]]);
  }
}
```

But when I leave one for-cycle and manually write nums of arrays (see below), It works and I get graph.

```
for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++){
  var t = new Date (time[i]);
  data.push([t,data_graph[0][i],data_graph[1][i]]);
}
```

I got idea to use temporary variable, but also with no success.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++){
   var data_temporary = [];
   var t = new Date (time[i]);
   for(var n = 0; n < 2; n++){
     data_temporary.push([data_graph[n][i]]);
   }
   data.push([t,data_temporary]);
 }
```

So my question is...where could be a problem?
Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your three code snippets generate three different `data` structures:

1. `[t, [datagraph…], [datagraph…], t, [datagraph…], [datagraph…], …]`
2. `[[t, datagraph…, datagraph…], [t, datagraph…, datagraph…], …]`
3. `[[t, [[datagraph…], [datagraph…]]], [t, [[datagraph…], [datagraph…]]], …]`

Too often you pushed one-element-arrays, btw.

So if you want struc#2 generated by a loop, use

```
for (var i=0; i<time.length; i++) {
    var t = new Date (time[i]);
    var temp = [t]; // or temp=[]; temp.push(t);
    for (var j=0; j<data_graph.length; j++) // or j<2 if that's certain
        temp.push(data_graph[j][i]);
    data.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi for you advice. Problem is solved! At this moment javascript push() is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The second (working) version creates a two dimension array with `time.length` elements in the first dimension each containing three elements `[t, x, y]`, as required.

In the first version you are creating a one-dimensional array `[t0, [x0], [y0], t1, [x1], [y1], ...]`.

Your third version doesn't work because whilst you correctly create `time.length` elements in the first dimension, the elements themselves are `[t, [[x], [y]]]`, and not `[t, x, y]`.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to push() creates a new element in your `data` array. So, in your first example, you are passing 3 objects on each iteration of the outer `for` loop, and in the third example you are passing an object that consists of time and an array of two values. But the dygraph script apparently expects objects consisting of three elements, so your second example works.